# Search a text/element in UIAElementArray

Tags: objective-c, arrays, ios6, ios-ui-automation

I am dealing with UIAElementArray for the ios automation and looking for an easier way to search inside the UIAElementArray.

Below is the code:

```
var textArray = this.myCollectionViews.staticTexts();

textArray.toArray() // Trying to convert UIAElementArray to a javascript array.

logger.logDebug('Array object is' + textArray); // Here the output is [object UIAElementArray]; which I guess should be Array and not UIAElementArray.

if (textArray.indexOf('Hello') > -1) 
{
       // do this
}
```

Here I am getting a crash on textArray.indexOf :

```
TypeError: '[object UIAElementNil]' is not a function (evaluating 'textArray.indexOf('Hello')')
```

Has anybody tried converting UIAElementArray to javascript array using toArray() method? Or any ideas to make an easier search inside UIAElementArray?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can search using predicates. I'm not quite sure what you're trying to accomplish, but it looks like you want to do something if a text label exists. I would implement it like so:

```
if (textArray.withPredicate('name contains "Hello"').length > 0)
{
    // do this
}
```

You can build predicates that work on any property of a `UIAElement`, we're doing `name()` in this case.

Here's [Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html) on the basics of the predicate string format.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, yes I am checking if the text exists, but later I would also need the index of that text in that textArray and hence was trying to make use of indexOf() method. Can try making use of withPredicate(), but wonder why toArray() is not returning me a javascript array.